# What if My Word is not in Bert model vocabulary?

Tags: keras, bert

I am doing NER using Bert Model. I have encountered some words in my datasets which is not a part of bert vocabulary and i am getting the same error while converting words to ids. Can someone help me in this?

Below is the code i am using for bert.

````
df = pd.read_csv("drive/My Drive/PA_AG_123records.csv",sep=",",encoding="latin1").fillna(method='ffill')

!wget --quiet https://raw.githubusercontent.com/tensorflow/models/master/official/nlp/bert/tokenization.py

import tensorflow_hub as hub
import tokenization
module_url = 'https://tfhub.dev/tensorflow/bert_en_uncased_L-12_H-768_A-12/2'
bert_layer = hub.KerasLayer(module_url, trainable=True)

vocab_file = bert_layer.resolved_object.vocab_file.asset_path.numpy()
do_lower_case = bert_layer.resolved_object.do_lower_case.numpy()
tokenizer = tokenization.FullTokenizer(vocab_file, do_lower_case)

tokens_list=['hrct',
 'heall',
 'government',
 'of',
 'hem',
 'snehal',
 'sarjerao',
 'nawale',
 '12',
 '12',
 '9999',
 'female',
 'mobile',
 'no',
 '1155812345',
 '3333',
 '3333',
 '3333',
 '41st',
 '3iteir',
 'fillow']

max_len =25
text = tokens_list[:max_len-2]
input_sequence = ["[CLS]"] + text + ["[SEP]"]
print("After adding  flasges -[CLS] and [SEP]: ")
print(input_sequence)


tokens = tokenizer.convert_tokens_to_ids(input_sequence )
print("tokens to id ")
print(tokens)
```
````

Comment: BERT uses subword vocabularies, and normally have no out-of-vocabulary word problems (see [How pre-trained BERT model generates word embeddings for out of vocabulary words?](https://datascience.stackexchange.com/questions/85566/how-pre-trained-bert-model-generates-word-embeddings-for-out-of-vocabulary-words) ).

Comment: No, I am still getting error

Comment: What specific errors are you getting? With what input words?

Comment: the word is 'hrct' and it is getting error that it has no any key value.

Comment: I fear , i have many words which will not be in vocabulary

Comment: Given that BERT does not have OOV word problems with Latin script words, I think this may be related to the BERT implementation you are using or to how you are using it. If you copy here the code you are using, we may be able to help better.

Comment: I am updating my question with the code

Comment: @noe I have updated the code , please have a look.

Comment: Please consider marking the answer as correct if deemed so.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is that you are **not** using BERT's tokenizer properly.

Instead of using BERT's tokenizer to actually tokenize the input text, you are splitting the text in tokens yourself, in your `token_list` and then requesting the tokenizer to give you the IDs of those tokens. However, if you provide tokens that are not part of the BERT subword vocabulary, it will not be able to handle them.

You must not do this.

Instead, you should let the tokenizer tokenize the text and then ask for the token IDs, e.g.:

```
tokens_list = tokenizer.tokenize('Where are you going?')
```

Remember, nevertheless, that [BERT uses subword tokenization](https://datascience.stackexchange.com/a/85570/14675), so it will split the input text so that it can be represented with the subwords in its vocabulary.

Comment: OK, Thanks for clarification