# How to handle OOV in non-contextual embedding (word2vec, Glove, FastText)?

Tags: machine-learning, deep-learning, nlp, tensorflow, pytorch

how non-contextual embedding (Word2Vec, Glove, FastText) handle OOV (incase if given word is not available in vocabulary)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the case of [word2vec](https://arxiv.org/abs/1301.3781) and [GloVe](https://aclanthology.org/D14-1162/), the out-of-vocabulary (OOV) problem is usually addressed by simply ignoring the OOV word. That is, act as if the word were not present in the text since the beginning. There is not much of an alternative, because they are simply tables that associate a word with a vector. If some word is not on the table, then you may try to find a similar word by other means (e.g. a synonym dictionary) and use its vector instead, but normally it is not worth it and the most cost-effective solution is to simply drop the word.

For [FastText](https://arxiv.org/abs/1607.04606) the issue is different because it works with character n-grams: a word embedding is simply the sum of its n-gram vectors plus the vector of the word itself. Therefore, if the n-grams of the OOV word are in the embedding, FastText would still be able to give you a representation for it.

Comment: that means in FastText, embedding works on character/ subword level? @noe

Comment: FastText embeddings receive information at both character n-gram and word levels and compute the embeddings at word level.

Comment: in above for FastText: you referred 'word embedding is the sum of n-gram vectors PLUS the vector of the word itself. how do we get vector of the word (since the word mapping is not available ) @noe

Comment: The vector of the word itself is also part of the embeddings table, along with the n-grams.

Comment: @tovijayak do you have any further doubts about my answer?

Comment: Thank you @ noe