# How can i get the vector of word using BERT?

Tags: nlp, word-embeddings, bert, representation

I need to get word-vectors using BERT and got this function that i think it should be the one i need

```
def get_bert_embed_matrix(sentences):
    device = torch.device("cuda:0" if torch.cuda.is_available() else "cpu")
    model_config = transformers.AutoConfig.from_pretrained('bert-base-uncased', output_hidden_states=True)
    model = transformers.AutoModel.from_pretrained('bert-base-uncased', config=model_config)
    tokenizer = transformers.AutoTokenizer.from_pretrained('bert-base-uncased')  
   for i in sentences:
        tokenized_text = tokenizer.tokenize(i)
        indexed_tokens = tokenizer.convert_tokens_to_ids(tokenized_text)        
        tokens_tensor = torch.tensor([indexed_tokens])
        model.eval()
        outputs = model(tokens_tensor)
        hidden_states = outputs[2]
        word_embed_6 = torch.cat([hidden_states[i] for i in [-1,-2,-3,-4]], dim=-1)
    return word_embed_6
```

Does the method return vectors for sub-word or word ?

Comment: You need to provide more context in order to get a proper answer on this.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: thanks for replying to the post . i clarified my problem, please see it . Thanks

Comment: A full discussion on BERT Word Embeddings can be found here https://mccormickml.com/2019/05/14/BERT-word-embeddings-tutorial/ with a colab notebook here https://colab.research.google.com/drive/1yFphU6PW9Uo6lmDly_ud9a6c4RCYlwdX

Answer (score 2):

About the first piece of code you posted:

At least from the apparent behavior, I would say your code computes the average of all subword vectors in a sentence, not for each word.

To compute word-level representations, you should average only the subwords belonging to a specific word, not all subwords in the sentence.

As a side note, I would suggest not to reuse variable names, as it makes the code confusing. In your code, you reuse `i`.

---

About the second piece of code you posted:

It seems to add up the subword embeddings of each word (only the last BERT layer) and concatenate each resulting vector into a tensor for the whole sentence (whose length would be the number of words).

Comment: thank a lot for answering but excuse me do you mean that i need to loop in words not sentences right ? i mean here in this line `for w in words:` instead of `for i in sentences:` if so how can i get words in the sentences , does tokenization return them ?

Comment: I updated my answer referring to the second piece of code you posted.

Comment: thanks a lot for replying. my specific task if i need to represent the embedding layer for image captioning task i need to represent the vectors for each word in the sentence so if you please do you see that the second code is suitable for this task ? i updated my question too with my result

Comment: exucse me i read that the word embedding by concatenating the last four layers(word_emb_6), giving us a single word vector per token. Each vector will have a length 4 x 768 = 3,072. All other word embeddings have the 768 length vectors per token. I'm confused about sub-words and words embedding in BERT